# How do I make a basketball rim in Flash?

Tags: flash, object, movieclip

I am making a simple basketball game and this is what i have so far http://amazonproducts.netai.net/game/bball.html .The problem is the rim, what I did is I added 4 small movie clips on the end of the rim (far left) and this is the code I used for them:

```
if (ball.hitTest(rimleft)) {
xspeed= Math.abs(xspeed) * -1;
}
if (ball.hitTest(rimright)) {
xspeed= Math.abs(xspeed);

}
if (ball.hitTest(rimtop)) {
yspeed*=-1;
}
if (ball.hitTest(rimbot)) {
yspeed*=-1;
}
```

As you can see it's not working good, some times ball just passes through the hoop, sometimes it gets stuck or it bounces weird. Could you please give me a better idea how to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Luka, I wasn't able to access your link due to the site being blocked by a school web protection program. However, maybe I can still point you in the right direction. Try something along this line (the `rim` has the instance name `rim`. Forget the left and right rim thing for now):

```
var difficulty:int=10;
var depth_matches:Boolean=false;
if(ball.hitTestObject(rim)&&depth_matches){
    if(ball.x>rim.x-(rim.width/2)+difficulty && ball.x<rim.x+(rim.width/2)-difficulty){
        ball.x=rim.x;
    your_score++;
    }
}
```

The Boolean `depth_matches` describes whether or not the ball is at the same depth as your rim (I'm assuming that the game doesn't involve dropping the ball into the hoop but rather throwing it). Since I'm not looking at your code and I can't see what method you're using for this game, you'll have to adapt it to your situation. It also appears that you are using `AS2`, so you'll have to change `hitTestObject` to `hitTest`.

Comment: Thanks for this but I actually got points working, the thing I need is the ball bouncing off the left side of the rim. That is what bothers me, you can see the ball get's stuck sometimes or just passes through the rim. I added those 4 movie clips next to eachother to bounce the ball but it's not working good :\